# Changes to php.ini have no effect

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, lamp, bitnami

When I look at the results of phpinfo() it shows my load configuration file as /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini. However, when I make changes to this file and restart apache those changes are not reflected. In fact I tried renaming php.ini and restarting apache and php ran just fine and phpinfo() still reports /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini as the loaded config file even though it doesnt exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bitnami stack uses php-fpm cacheing so I had to run

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
```

Comment: Can you set your answer as solved ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "ubuntu" tag is correct, I imagine that Apache is using the php.ini file in its normal place, rather then the one you edited.  Try editing /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini